# Agent Analyst extension for ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-10.0, simulation, agent-analyst

I am trying to create agent based model for simulating movement of occupants in different rooms of different floors of a building. I am using Agent Analyst tutorial downloaded from ESRI website and PhD dissertation of Elizabeth Groff as a guide.

Since the building has three different floors, I have created a 3D network dataset and created a toolboox which can find shortest route, closest facility and OD matrix from room centre to all the emergency exits.

I have created the following according to the two guides above.

1. csv file containing the activity space (i.e. the door of the room occupied, nearest exits of the floor, bends on the staircase and exit of the ground floor).
2. Point shapefile of path that the agents have to follow.
3. csv file containing the list of all neighbouring nodes.
4. Point shapefile of occupants. There are more than one occupants in few rooms. I intend to show the movement of these occupants as vector agents in Agent Analyst.
5. Point shapefile of all emergency exits. I also want it to be include in the model.

So I want to:

1. Show the movement of these agents from their present location to the nearest exit on ground floor.
2. The occupants are of different sex and age, thus I want the agents to move at different speed from one node to another and while they are moving downstairs. How can I do that?

Lastly, can anyone tell me if movement of agents can be shown in ArcScene because I tried to show the movement, it does not. I tried the same in ArcMap and it works. I haven't tried the same in ArcGlobe.

I am using ArcGIS 10 and Agent Analyst extension for ArcGIS.

Comment: Hello Andre, This is the link to her thesis. http://drum.lib.umd.edu/bitstream/1903/3775/2/egroff_diss_final.pdf